# Clean up data frame table when information column matches and certain keywords in data column matches

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

We have collected a lot of data but the data collection table was badly created

Poor table

[image: 1]

As we match the first three columns and environment condition (grabbing room condition), a clean table should look like the following:

cleaned table

[image: 2]

(This is a very simplified version of the bigger file)
Below is the csv file:

```
Personnel ID,Education,Origin,Typing speed (words/min),Typing environment,Reading speed (pages/min),Reading environment,Sit up speed (sit up/min),Sit up environment
110,College,Town A,105,Type English (quiet room),,,,
110,College,Town A,,,3,Read English (quiet room),,
110,College,Town A,,,,,20,Sit up (quiet room)
110,College,Town A,90,Type English (soft music room),,,,
110,College,Town A,,,2.5,Read English (soft music room),,
110,College,Town A,,,,,23,Sit up (soft music room)
110,College,Town A,87,Type English (loud music room),,,,
110,College,Town A,,,2,Read English (loud music room),,
110,College,Town A,,,,,25,Sit up (loud music room)
111,College,Town B,110,Type English (quiet room),,,,
111,College,Town B,,,3.5,Read English (quiet room),,
111,College,Town B,,,,,20,Sit up (quiet room)
111,College,Town B,104,Type English (soft music room),,,,
111,College,Town B,,,3,Read English (soft music room),,
111,College,Town B,,,,,23,Sit up (soft music room)
111,College,Town B,92,Type English (loud music room),,,,
111,College,Town B,,,2,Read English (loud music room),,
112,Highschool,Town A,95,Type English (quiet room),,,,
112,Highschool,Town A,,,2.5,Read English (quiet room),,
112,Highschool,Town A,,,,,,
112,Highschool,Town A,88,Type English (loud music room),,,,
112,Highschool,Town A,,,2.2,Read English (loud music room),,
113,Highschool,Town B,97,Type English (quiet room),,,,
113,Highschool,Town B,,,3,Read English (quiet room),,
113,Highschool,Town B,,,,,23,Sit up (soft music room)
113,Highschool,Town B,81,Type English (loud music room),,,,
113,Highschool,Town B,,,2,Read English (loud music room),,
113,Highschool,Town B,90,Type French (quiet room),,,,
113,Highschool,Town B,,,2.5,Read French (quiet room),,
113,Highschool,Town B,80,Type French (soft music room),,,,
113,Highschool,Town B,,,1.5,Read French (loud music room),,
113,Highschool,Town B,,,,,25,Sit up (loud music room)
```

I am not to familiar with python and pandas df.
I tried figuring out using bash but removing "," from csv file made column # reading hard in awk as they are empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of trying to mix and match.
Split the table making into separate data frames.

Keeping:

1. create a new column call Condition --> keep quiet, soft, loud
2. break the df up to the following subsets
   Personnel ID, Education, Origin, Typing speed, Typing Condition, Condition
   Personnel ID, Education, Origin, Reading speed, Reading Condition, Condition
   Personnel ID, Education, Origin, Sit up speed, Sit up Condition, Condition
3. merged_df = df.merge(df1,df2,how="left",on=["Personnel ID","Education","Origin","Condition"])
4. repeat until all columns are merged in and remove duplicates

We can consider this close.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).